# Verständnisfrage/Bezug von „darauffolgend“

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-choice, etymology

Bezieht sich das Wort „darauffolgend“ auf das aktuelle Objekt? Ich habe nach einer Art „hier(r)auffolgend“ gesucht, aber dieses Wort scheint es nicht zu geben. Ich suche den Begriff, der „das auf dieses (aktuelle/vorliegende) Element folgende“ beschreibt. 
Ist das gesuchte Wort „darauffolgend“? Oder gibt es etwas anderes hierfür in der deutschen Sprache?
Und zum weiteren Verständnis: das Wort „darauffolgend“ bildet sich doch aus [„da“ (=„dort“?) + „r“ + Präposition „auf“ + „folgend“], oder?

Comment: Siehe [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/darauffolgend). Zur Etymologie: ["darauf"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/darauf) (= auf diese Sache) + "folgend". Ansonsten: Kontext, bitte

Comment: Der/die/das nachfolgende ... ?

Comment: Es gibt "hierrauffolgend", wird nur selten benutzt. Verstehen tut es aber jeder, würde ich sagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jain. Es kommt drauf an, was du gerade unter 'aktuelles Objekt' verstehst.

Der Unterschied liegt darin, ob du 'auf ein Objekt verweist' oder ob du 'dich auf dem Objekt befindest'.

Ich kann's nicht besser ausdrücken, daher ein Beispiel:

> Ich zeige ihnen nun ein aktuelles Foto, darauffolgend ein Foto von vor 10 Jahren.

Hier liegt ein Verweis auf ein Objekt vor. Das ist wie auf ein Objekt mit dem Finger zeigen und sagen "Darauf folgt" oder "Auf dieses Foto dort folgt...".
Wenn kein Verweis dieser Art vorliegt, kannst du *darauffolgend* nicht verwenden.

> Sie sehen gerade ein aktuelles Foto. Nehmen sie sich Zeit, sich das Foto anzuschauen. Hierauffolgend werde ich ihnen ein Foto von vor 10 Jahren zeigen.

Die Verwendung von *hierauf* signalisiert, dass man sich auf das Foto bezieht, also das aktuelle Objekt, das der Zuschauer betrachtet. Das ist was ich mit 'auf dem Objekt' befinden meinte, wir referenzieren es nicht. Weil wir nicht auf das Foto zeigen, können wir nicht sagen "Darauf folgt", sondern nur "Hierauf folgt" oder "Auf das Foto hier folgt".
Strikt genommen kann man im letzten Satz natürlich auch *darauffolgend* verwenden, wenn man sich auf den zweiten Satz bezieht. *Darauffolgend* würde dann bedeuten: "Nachdem sie sich das Foto angeschaut haben".

Um die Frage zu beantworten: *Darauffolgend* bezieht sich auf das aktuelle Objekt, auf das man zeigt. 'Befindet' man sich auf dem Objekt, ist das Wort ungeeignet. *Hierauffolgend* ist aber kein gängiges deutsches Wort. Es gibt einige Google-Hits (wobei meistens *darauffolgend* richtig gewesen wäre), aber nahezu keine offiziele Referenz definiert das Wort (das heißt ich habe keine gefunden).

Alternativen sind kontextabhängig. Da du leider keinen Kontext definiert hast, kann ich nur einige Möglichkeiten auflisten:

- anschließend
- folgend
- nachfolgend
- das folgende
- das nachfolgende
- das nächste
- dann
- darauf
- im Anschluss
- in der Folge

Comment: wow. Danke für die aufschlussreiche Antwort! Das zweite Beispiel entspricht ist exakt dem, was ich zu beschreiben versuchte. Ich denke, ich werde es mit „nachfolgend“ oder „das hierauf folgende…“ versuchen. Danke!!

Comment: @Herr_Schwabullek Beim nochmaligen Drüberlesen ist mir aufgefallen, dass strikt genommen die Rede von "Objekt" falsch ist. Es wird nicht Bezug auf das Objekt (Foto) genommen, sondern auf die Handlung des "Bild-Zeigens". Abgesehen davon bleibt die Antwort aber bestehen.

Comment: i just heard about this word "jain" and i see it in the answer above. does it really mean "yes and no"?